# update last row in sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to make a query that updates the last row in my table. here is the query I'm using:

```
String updateQuery = "Update table set col = '"+ bla +"' where id=SELECT max(id)";
```

but this gives mean error..I know how to update last row in SQL but I can't figure it out in SQLITE. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try one of the two options

Option 1

```
UPDATE table set col = 1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)
```

Option 2

Split it in two seperate queries. in first make select to take max id, in second update the value using id as a variable

The second option will work for 100%, I'm not sure the first but it should